# jvm error 545 in blackberry phone

Tags: blackberry

I have a software program in my blackberry bold 9000,It shows 'jvm error 545'.
To recover I connect phone to blackberry desktop manager but it doen't detect the phone.So Itry to reinstall ,for that I connect phone to system and execute loader.exe in Apploader folder.But it also failed.It show a message
"The Blackberry desktop software doen't have blackberry device software for the device that have connected to the computer.contact your wireless serrvice provider or system administrator"

Answer (score 0):

try downloading JLCmder and install it and run it as

1)you can carry out 2nd option ,remove corrupted COD file alone as given in the below link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Curve/JVM-Error-102-BEFORE-YOU-WIPE-YOUR-SYSTEM/td-p/92398

you always have a chance to get it worked than wiping th device

2)Wipe the OS using 4th option

All these options that i have told is only for if  the device got corrupted

Comment: Is your device corrupted or app not working,whether JLCmder is not opening or not

Comment: Hey Rakesh i tried the steps mentioned by you by while trying to go for the factory reset i am getting "javaloader" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: you could have installed JLCmder in a place,plz check with that amd move to it